# Trouble with ffmpeg on mac os catalina 10.15.3

Tags: ffmpeg

I had ffmpeg installed before upgrading my os to catalina.  When I tried to re-encode a video it complained with this message

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      ffmpeg
```

I found out openssl isn't used in catalina in favor for libressl.. 
I did a brew search openssl and found I have openssl@1.1 not 1.0.0

I'm weary about messing around with the version of openssl because so many other programs depend on it and I don't want to screw up my system..

My question is how can I get ffmpeg to run on my system?  Mac os catalina 10.15.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using homebrew then `brew reinstall ffmpeg` fixed this issue for me.

Comment: This is because the [formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/ffmpeg.rb) uses `--enable-gnutls` instead, and will leave openssl untouched.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me (found it on a random search, did not save source, sorry):

1. Open the location of the ffmpeg executable (e.g. /usr/local/bin) in **Finder**.
   (This itself might pose a problem since Finder won't show these directories if you just navigate from "Mac OS Hard Drive".  You can chdir to this directory in a Terminal, then "open ." - this will force a Finder window to open with this directory.)
2. Right-click on the ffmpeg executable, then choose "Open with... Terminal".  A new Terminal window opens, then you get the message "Mac OS doesn't know this - so eff off" or something to that effect.  Click "cancel".
3. Do Step 2 again.  This time it pops up a window saying "are you sure... ?!" or some such.  Select "Yes, open, damnit!" (or maybe just "Open"). A Terminal window flashes and disappears.

But now Mac OS knows ffmpeg should be allowed to run, so it should run however triggered.

You have to do it for the other modules, like ffplay, I think.

Hope this helps.  I too am tired of fighting MAC OS trying hard to look like they are not built on FreeBSD, even though that is the very value of Mac OS to many of us.  I am THIS close to switching to Linux, and saving a lot of money.